# Generate styled JSX from text input form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm designing a website for a friend of mine using React. I've created a discography page for the site which I want him to be able to update himself through a form with text input fields at a separate URL.

What I need to be able to do is take the text he inputs and image he uploads and, on submission of the form, display the new information in the Discography section of the site, styled according to the CSS of the Discography component. I'm looking for suggestions on how to do this as I have no clue.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: you can use the state and pass it to the component for this one you have several approaches, passing via props, using context, using redux which is a external library

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Can you explain more about how I might achieve this using context?